# :nth-of-type(odd) getting non-targeted elements

Tags: html, css

I'm making a list, and I'm using `:nth-of-type(odd)` to give the odd ones a background.

```
.item {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 0px 0;
}
.item:nth-of-type(odd){
  background: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="text-right">
  <small>
    <a href="./?action=edit">Edit Info</a>
  </small>
</p>
  <p class="item">
    <b>Name</b>
    <span class="value"><?= $user["f_name"]; ?> <?= $user["l_name"]; ?></span>
  </p>
  <p class="item">
    <b>Email</b>
    <span class="value"><?= $user["email"] ? $user["email"] : "-"; ?></span>
  </p>
  <p class="item">
    <b>Phone</b>
    <span class="value"><?= $user["phone"] ? phone_format($user["phone"]) : "-"; ?></span>
  </p>
```

When I tried this, the first `p` (with `.text-right`) was included in the `:nth-of-type` so that the first `.item` was counted as second.

I managed to fix it by wrapping the `.item`s in a `div`, but this won't work with my layout. Is there a way that I can do this while still having all of the `p`s in the same parent container?

Comment: `nth-of-type` refers to the element, not the class.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The first `p` in the target classes scope?

Comment: Because if not then if I had something like `#container div:nth-of-type(odd)`, it would get every div, regardless of whether it's in `#container` or not.

Comment: What outcome do you want?